# Can we configure groups in Azure AD SAML Assertion

Tags: azure, saml, azure-active-directory

As per 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/, we should get groups in the assertion, as follows:

```
<Attribute Name="../claims/groups">
<AttributeValue>07dd8a60-bf6d-4e17-8844-230b77145381</AttributeValue>
```

But in the assertion I get I don't see the group attributes.

Also when trying to add an attribute to the SAML token for a given application, I can add only regular user attributes like givenName, surname etc. I don't see  group attributes in the drop down.

Some sites on the internet talk about downloading and uploading some manifest or using a Graph API call.  Am I missing any configuration option which can enable the groups to appear in the assertion?

Answer (score 2):

To see the groups as claims in the assertions, refer: [Using Group Claims in Azure Active Directory](http://rickrainey.com/2015/02/13/using-group-claims-in-azure-active-directory/)

In the manifest, change the groupMembershipClaims property (which will be set to null) to SecurityGroup and then save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the "new" type of Azure AD integrated application. There are several ways to register your app with Azure AD. One allows you to download, edit and then upload a manifest. This version allows configuring the app to issue group claims and application roles. The newer way, which you seem to be using, is launched from the "add an application from the gallery" wizard and then selecting "custom". This type allows for configuring SAML claims, but does not allow you to edit any manifest. Unfortunately there is no way to combine the two, that I know of.

Morgan

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD identity provider provides group membership details in 5 different formats as below,
[image: Azure Ad Group membership claims]

Out of these, *Group ID* represents the id of groups in Azure Active directory and the remaining 4 attributes provide values from the on-prem Active directory only if Azure AD is in sync with the on-prem Active directory.

In the case of Okta and ping identity, it’s possible to directly forward the raw value of memberOf attribute ***{CN=group name, DC=domainname}***(i.e. X500 distinguished name format) received from on-prem AD in SAML assertion.

But in the case of Azure Ad, it’s not possible to forward the raw value of memberOf attribute from Azure AD to SAML assertion as it is, instead Azure AD had already parsed group membership attribute internally and given the above 4 ways to forward the group membership information to the service provider through SAML assertion token.